# Where can I make a suggestion to this site?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I’ve seen questions whose **accepted** answers are, at least for me, definitely not the “best” ones.

I’m aware that *accepted* don’t mean *correct*. “It just means that it worked to the person that made the question”. However, I have a suggestion that could improve the *accepted* to “best” answer ratio.

Where should I place the suggestion that I have? I don’t think I can make a suggestion as a question. Can I?

Comment: Why do you think you can't and why what would be the point of the "feature-request" tag if you can't? I would also suggest you search for previous feature requests regarding the "accepted answer" tick, since where are several of them, which have been handled already.

Comment: Did you try to browse questions tagged with [tag:feature-request] before posting this question?

Comment: @Tom. Because it **is** a suggestion and **not** a question. A **Yes** or **No** answer is still an answer. For the Tag that can be removed if anyone feels so.

Comment: Meta is different. Voting is different here and the usage of "questions" is different. You are welcome to post feature requests here... and they **are** questions... "can we add ____ feature?".

Comment: Considering that this isn't a duplicate, I'm not sure why this was downvoted. It seems like a legitimate question

Answer (score 10):

You post a question on this site with the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag.

That marks it as a feature request for this (and all our other Q&A) sites, as the tag description says.